# Как определить размер MTU?

Tags: сеть, роутер, пакет, ethernet, mtu

Я что-то запутался в фреймах (кадрах). Как рассчитывается не пойму? MTU должно быть постоянным или нет? - в моем роутере и на сетевой карте установлены разные значения по-умолчанию, причем в сетевой карте это значение больше.

И что входит в MTU - только полезная нагрузка или весь кадр? Информация по этому поводу противоречивая, где-то пишут, что это MTU - это весь кадр, где-то, что только полезная нагрузка. Как же оно на самом деле, кто-то по-любому нагло врет? Вряд ли принимающее устройство имея ограничение по MTU например 1500 задумывается: "так, что бы мне рассчитать - весь фрейм 1540 или полезную нагрузку 1500 ..... принимать или не принимать, как же быть..... error...error...... "

И непонятно, как принимающее устройство понимает, где заканчивается кадр, ведь согласно википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet полезная нагрузка может быть переменной, а общая длина кадра или длина полезной нагрузки не указывается?

Answer (score 1):

Maximum transmission unit (MTU) это максимальный объём данных, который может быть передан протоколом за одну итерацию. К примеру, Ethernet MTU равняется 1500, что означает, что максимальный объём данных, переносимый Ethernet фреймом не может превышать 1500 байт (без учёта Ethernet заголовка и FCS (frame check sequence).

Нет, не нужно увеличивать это значение по причине: если на интерфейс попадает пакет, превосходящий установленное IP MTU, пакет либо подвергается фрагментации, либо, в случае установленного флага DF (DO NOT Fragment) в IP заголовке, отменяется, а устройство сгенерирует (не всегда, правда) ICMP сообщение Fragmentation Needed и отправить его назад отправителю исходного пакета. Поэтому превышать установленную в сетевой карте величину без особой на то нужды я бы не стал. Можно даже, пропинговав следующие маршрутизаторы пакетами разной длины с установленным флагом DF, определить, какой максимальный MTU тот будет принимать без фрагментации. Велики шансы, что размер будет даже меньше, нежели 1500.

Есть [хорошая статья на Хабре, объясняющая ряд моментов](https://habrahabr.ru/post/227729/).

Comment: Подождите, но если я поставлю MTU скажем 3000, то пакет сразу пройдет, не нужно будет ничего фрагментировать, отменять, верно? - это экономия времени.  А это точно, что в значение MTU входят только полезные данные, без заголовков и прочего, поскольку информация на разных сайтах по этому поводу противоречивая?

Comment: Через мой рутер (1400 с чем-то, сейчас лезть не хочется) если DF сброшен, он будет фрагментирован, если выставлен, никуда не пойдёт. Вы можете выставить в своем рутере и 5000 (если нет софтовых или аппаратных ограничений), но вам ничего это не даст (есть шанс, что и по голове от провайдера может прилететь). Правильно считать именно полезные данные, но в каждом приходе свой служка, поэтому необходимо уточнять.

Comment: Почему это ничего не даст? Если тем самым я говорю, что можно пропускать большие пакеты без фрагментации?

Comment: Как вы это говорите? Выставив DF? Пакет просто никуда не пойдёт. Его не пропустят на первом же рутере, где вы не хозяин. Если не выставите, он  будет фрагментирован.

Comment: А тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/226807/ говорится, что в MTU входят не только полезные данные, но и заголовок. Почему в моей сетевой карте и роутере по-умолчанию установлены разные значения? Это неправильно? Получается при каждой передаче каждого пакета он будет фрагментироваться? И все же какой размер MTU должен быть, чтобы ничего не фрагментировались 1500 (какой размер правильный)?  Как принимающее устройство понимает, где заканчивается кадр, ведь согласно википедии полезная нагрузка может быть переменной, а общая длина кадра или длина полезной нагрузки не указывается?